# JSONDoc doesn't detect @ApiObject annotation of models in multimodule projects

Tags: spring-boot, jsondoc

With Spring Boot, JsonDoc nicely detects all the controllers but it doesn't detect models which are located in another maven module.

Our project has 2 modules:

- my-app-core
- my-app-impl

The main controllers as well as properties files e.g. application.properties are located in *my-app-core* and the followings are jsondoc's configurations:

```
# mandatory configuration
jsondoc.version=1.0
jsondoc.basePath=http://localhost:8090
jsondoc.packages[0]=com.myapp
jsondoc.packages[1]=com.myapp.api.docs.GlobalDocumentation
jsondoc.packages[2]=com.myapp.api.docs.ChangeLogDocumentation
jsondoc.packages[3]=com.myapp.api.jsonapi.model
# optional configuration
jsondoc.playgroundEnabled=true
jsondoc.displayMethodAs=URI
```

The package *com.myapp.api.jsonapi.model* is in the other module *my-app-impl* and JSONDoc doesn't detect them.

Below is a sample annotated model

```
@JsonApiResource(type="advisers")
@ApiObject(description = "Adviser model")
public class Adviser {
    @JsonApiId
    @ApiObjectField(description = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @ApiObjectField(description = "Adviser's name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem.My Jsondoc version is 1.2.19.
I found this issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/fabiomaffioletti/jsondoc/issues/244
They may caused with same reason.
The code just detect the method with @RequestMapping annotation and if you not use it as method's param or return value, it can't find the Adviser Object.
Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks. We completely removed JSONDoc from our project as we had other issues with it

Comment: I also found some other issue, now change to swagger